# Creating and displaying a checkers board

Tags: clojure, ascii-art, checkers-draughts

I am learning clojure this week end and just starting to develop a simple checkers engine. I currently coded some basic functions to create the board and display it. I would love to get some feedback !

```
(ns sandbox.checkers)      

(def standard-size 10)     

(defn empty-board [size]   
  (vec (replicate size (vec (replicate size :empty)))))

(defn str-piece [piece]    
  (cond
    (= piece :empty) " "
    (= piece :white_man) "O"
    (= piece :black_man) "0"))

(defn str-board [board]    
  (str "\n"                
    (clojure.string/join   
      "\n"                 
      (map
        #(clojure.string/join " | " (map str-piece %))
        board))))

(defn print-board [board]
  (println (str-board board)))

(defn fill-white [size]
  (apply comp
  (map
    (fn [pos]
      (fn [board] (assoc-in board pos :white_man)))
      (for [x (range size)
            y (range (inc (/ size 2)) size) 
            :when (or (and (even? x) (even? y))
                      (and (odd? x) (odd? y)))]       
        [y x]))))

(defn fill-black [size]
  (apply comp
    (map
      (fn [pos]
        (fn [board] (assoc-in board pos :black_man)))
      (for [x (range size)
            y (range 0 (dec (/ size 2)))    
            :when (or (and (even? x) (even? y))
                      (and (odd? x) (odd? y)))]       
        [y x]))))

(defn starting-board [size]
  ((fill-black size) ((fill-white size) (empty-board size))))

(print-board (starting-board standard-size))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few small points

- `replicate` is deprecated. Use `repeat` instead.
- Use `-` instead of `_` in names.
- The `cond` in `str-piece` compares `piece` against a number of
  constants. Use `case` instead.
- Simplify the `:when` conditions to `(= (even? x) (even? y))`

This gives us

```
(ns sandbox.checkers)      

(def standard-size 10)     

(defn empty-board [size]   
  (vec (repeat size (vec (repeat size :empty)))))

(defn str-piece [piece]    
  (case piece
    :empty " "
    :white-man "O"
    :black-man "0"))

(defn str-board [board]    
  (str "\n"                
    (clojure.string/join   
      "\n"                 
      (map
        #(clojure.string/join " | " (map str-piece %))
        board))))

(defn print-board [board]
  (println (str-board board)))

(defn fill-white [size]
  (apply comp
         (map
           (fn [pos]
             (fn [board] (assoc-in board pos :white-man)))
           (for [x (range size)
                 y (range (inc (/ size 2)) size)
                 :when (= (even? x) (even? y))]
             [y x]))))

(defn fill-black [size]
  (apply comp
    (map
      (fn [pos]
        (fn [board] (assoc-in board pos :black-man)))
      (for [x (range size)
            y (range 0 (dec (/ size 2)))
            :when (= (even? x) (even? y))]       
        [y x]))))

(defn starting-board [size]
  ((fill-black size) ((fill-white size) (empty-board size))))

(print-board (starting-board standard-size))
```

---

Edited subsequently:

There are simpler ways to generate the lists of squares for `fill-white` and `fill-black`.

For a given row `y`, the required `x`s are `(range (mod y 2) size 2)`. The functions become

```
(defn fill-white [size]
  (apply comp
         (map
           (fn [pos] (fn [board] (assoc-in board pos :white-man)))
           (for [y (range (inc (/ size 2)) size)
                 x (range (mod y 2) size 2)]
             [y x]))))

(defn fill-black [size]
  (apply comp
         (map
           (fn [pos] (fn [board] (assoc-in board pos :black-man)))
           (for [y (range 0 (dec (/ size 2)))
                 x (range (mod y 2) size 2)]
             [y x]))))
```

---

**A thorough reworking**

The `fill...` functions construct and apply a sequence of functions, one function for each change to the empty board.

It is simpler to describe the repetitive pattern using functions `cycle` and `take`, with `vec` to convert to vectors:

```
(defn starting-board [size]
  (let [block (fn [rows piece]
                (let [source (cycle [piece :empty])
                      row-pair (map (comp vec (partial take size)) 
                                    [source (rest source)])]
                  (take rows (cycle row-pair))))
        block-size (dec (quot size 2))]
    (vec (concat (block block-size :black-man)
                 (block 2 :empty)
                 (block block-size :white-man)))))
```

Notice that the *same row vectors* are used again and again, not copies. This works in Clojure because vectors (and other native data structures) are *immutable*.